# Sharing variable's data across controller method via before/after filters or the session hash. Which way is better if filters allow this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So if in my before filter, I set an instance variable @myvar = "hello"
can the controller method that runs after the before filter have access to @myvar? I have an option to either use session to share the variable data across controller methods, or possibly structure the before/after filter chain in such a way that I can share the variable if possible. 
2 questions:

1. Does using before filter allow the method that runs after it to have the data set to instance variables of the method that runs before? Must they be instance variables or they can be normal ones without the @ sign?
2. If the above is possible, is it better than using the session hash to share the instance variable data?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes. Pretty popular for loading models. For example:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_user

  def show
  end

  private

  def load_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

@user is now set and accessible in your view. You can ripple that across other methods or use 'only' or 'except' to filter which of them they apply to.

Comment: Do you mean the class inherits from activeRecord or controller? Also, why is the better than using a session variable?

Comment: @TazMan: because you don't pollute the session with temp data.

Comment: I would say that you usually don't want to store things in the session unless you are doing something like a multi-page wizard or something that needs to persist temporarily across multiple pages without another object modifying it. If you want to store something on the user's browser, I'd probably use a cookie instead. Managing sessions can sometimes be a nightmare.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: why not? please explain an alternative way of doing this.. I have an `upload_status`endpoint that should have access to the other controller method's variable that is used to upload file. upload_status will be called from ajax via polling to see how much of file is uploaded. (status bar stuff)

Answer (score 1):

Stop thinking sharing instance variables across controller actions.

Each hit to an action creates a new instance of controller. `show` creates one, `index` creates on, and the same for other actions. They are different instances and CAN NOT share instance variables, of course.

I would also be against the idea to hide instance variables in filters, trying to "DRY" the code. Normally there's nothing to "DRY" as the instance variables are usually different in each action, though not absolutely. filters are not built for that usage.

Show them explicitly in action, this will help your peers, and yourself(after some days) to figure out what'll happen in this action.

Comment: Alright. But I have a need. I need to have access to variables being assigned to another controller. I have this complex action that has no route. It's called `initialize_processor(file_in)`. It opens the file and gathers stats and calculations on that file. Now I need these stats and calculations to be available on the page with the file upload button.

Comment: @TazMan, you can package the complex action into a private method under ApplicationController, and have multiple controller actions call it when needed.

Comment: lets say I add a method in the application controller that returns an instance of a ruby class that I can use. Lets say in one controller I set it's getters and setters. Will those values set in one controller of the object be visible in another?

Comment: This would be more complex. Instance variables in ApplicationController won't work as there is no extra ApplicationController instance generated when hitting sub controllers. This is possible with getter setter methods of class that starting with Rails App. You'd better post new question about the details.